# DB2 SQL Join and Max value

Tags: sql, join, db2, max

The database I'm accessing has two tables I need to query using DB2 SQL, shown here as nametable and addresstable.  The query is for finding all of the people with a certain balance due.  The addresses are stored in a separate table to keep track of address changes.  In addresstable, the latest address is determined by a sequence number (ADDRSEQUENCE).  The AddressID field is present in both tables, and is what ties each person to specific addresses.  The highest sequence number is the current address.  I need that current address for each person and only that one. I know I'm going to have to use MAX somewhere for the sequence number, but I can't figure out how to position it given the join.  Here's my current query, which of course returns all addresses...

```
SELECT NAMETABLE.ACCTNUM AS ACCOUNTNUMBER, 
NAMETABLE.NMELASTBUS AS LASTNAME,
NAMETABLE.NAME_FIRST AS FIRSTNAME, 
NAMETABLE.BALDUE AS BALANCEDUE,
ADDRESSTABLE.STREETNAME AS ADDR, 
ADDRESSTABLE.ADDRLINE2 AS 
ADDRLINE2,ADDRESSTABLE.CITYPARISH AS CITY, 
ADDRESSTABLE.ADDRSTATE AS STATE,
ADDRESSTABLE.ZIPCODE AS ZIP, 
ADDRESSTABLE.ADDIDSEQNO AS ADDRSEQUENCE
FROM NAMETABLE JOIN ADDRESSTABLE ON NAMETABLE.ADDRESSID = ADDRESSTABLE.ADDRESSID
WHERE NAMETABLE.BALANCEDUE >= '50.00'
```

Comment: ... Why is `NameTable.balanceDue` being queried with a string value?  It shouldn't be a string (char) data type - you should be using either `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a sub-select on the `MAX(ADDRSEQUENCE)` like so:

```
SELECT 
     N.ACCTNUM AS ACCOUNTNUMBER
    ,N.NMELASTBUS AS LASTNAME
    ,N.NAME_FIRST AS FIRSTNAME
    ,N.BALDUE AS BALANCEDUE
    ,A.STREETNAME AS ADDR, 
    ,A.ADDRLINE2 AS 
    ,A.ADDRLINE2
    ,A.CITYPARISH AS CITY, 
    ,A.ADDRSTATE AS STATE,
    ,A.ZIPCODE AS ZIP, 
FROM NAMETABLE AS N 
JOIN ADDRESSTABLE AS A 
  ON N.ADDRESSID = A.ADDRESSID
WHERE N.BALANCEDUE >= '50.00'
  AND A.ADDRSEQUENCE = (
    SELECT MAX(ADDRSEQUENCE)
    FROM ADDRESSTABLE AS A2
    WHERE A.ADDRESSID = A2.ADDRESSID
)
```

This is pretty quick in DB2.

Comment: Awesome.  This works perfectly.  I had it just about right, but couldn't figure out those last two lines.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row_number and partition by to do this. Something like this:

```
with orderedaddress as (
 select row_number() over (partition by ADDRESSID order by ADDRSEQUENCE desc) as rown,
 STREETNAME,ADDRESSID, ... from ADDRESSTABLE 
)
select NAMETABLE.ACCTNUM AS ACCOUNTNUMBER,
...
oa.STREETNAME 
...
from NAMETABLE JOIN orderedaddress oa on NAMETABLE.ADDRESSID = oa.ADDRESSID
where oa.rown = 1
and NAMETABLE.BALANCEDUE >= '50.00'
```

Comment: I'd have put `oa.rown = 1` in the join condition explicitly, although the optimizer's probably doing that automatically, given that it's an inner join.

Comment: yeah probably the optimizer will take care of that but inside join condition will definitely work too